# How to connect lav mic to an audio interface?

Tags: audio-interfaces, lavalier, connector

I have this lav mic:

[Amazon product link: Audio-Technica ATR3350 Omnidirectional Condenser Lavalier Microphone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002HJ9PTO)

And this audio interface:

[Amazon product link: BEHRINGER audio interface (UMC22)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FFIGZF6)

How can I connect the two?

I tried connecting the mic into my computer directly but the pre amplifiers are terrible.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same mic (ATR3350) and was dealing with this issue. The tip and ring are the same output, so you can use a splitter, that would divide the TRS to TR(left)/TR(right) and use either one of those outputs to plugin to the interface. This is the adapter I'm using (Hosa YMP-434).
Make sure you have phantom power OFF. You don't want to fry the microphone.
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0010D0HO0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0010D0HO0)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best sort of lavalier to use with pro/semi-pro interfaces. You need something that has both an XLR termination and an internal power adapter from 48v phantom to the electret bias.

It may be possible to connect this lavalier, but I can't be sure it will work.

You will need to unbalance the output of the TRS connector:

Tip -> XLR Pin 2
Ring/Sleeve -> XLR Pin 1 and 3

It's not clear what the purpose of the ring connector on the lavalier is being used for. Signal is most likely Tip/Sleeve.